# Python Selenium scraping: How do I extract elements from a Cloudflare-bypassed website?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, screen-scraping

```
import time

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.5615.165 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("accept=*/*")

s = Service(executable_path='C:\Program Files (x86)\Google')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)

driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
    'source': '''
        delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Array;
        delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Promise;
        delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Symbol;
  '''
})

driver.maximize_window()

def get_html(url):
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        page_source = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,"lxml")
        find_element = soup.find_all(class_="carousel-module--scroll-item--2CpA_")
        time.sleep(60)
        for item in find_element:
            with open ("test.txt","a","encoding='utf-8'") as file:
                file.write(item)
        time.sleep(60)

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    finally:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()


def main():
    get_html("https://www.udemy.com")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have tried to scrap udemy website, i used selenium to get through cloudlare. But i stuck into problem that i don't know how to scrap elements this way. Please Help!

I tried aiohttp Client Session, also i tried to use bs4, but nothing helps and i couldn't find solution all around interenet

Comment: Which elements are you trying to extract?

Comment: I am trying to extract cards and then scrap name and price